# Getting Magento shipment weight

Tags: magento

I'd like to know the weight of an order, as calculated by Magento. Anybody know where this is calculated in the code?

I'd eventually like to add it to the order info in the admin area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The weight of each order is already calculated and stored, look at the `sales_flat_order` table to see. To retrieve the weight for any given order use it's `getWeight()` method.